# insert large amount of data to cassandra efficiently

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I want to insert around 50 million rows ( ~ 30 columns each) into cassandra, currently only have 1 node.

I am querying my data from another data source and store in a table object. I iterate through parse each of the row individually then add it to the mutator. Currently I am inserting 100 rows at a time and 1 million rows takes 40 minutes! How do I speed up this process? ( I have also tried client.batch_mutate() but it seems to have reset connection error after a few thousand inserts of blocksize 2).

Through searching around I see that multi-threading could help. But I could not find any examples, could someone link me? thank you !!

My current code:

```
        List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> colValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        SomeTable result = Query(...); // this contains my result set of 1M rows initially

        for (Iterator itr = result.getRecordIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                String colName =.....
                String colValue = .....

            int colCount = colNames.size(); // 100 * 30

            for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
                //add row keys and columns to mutator 
                mutator.addInsertion(String.valueOf(rowCounter), "data", HFactory.createStringColumn(colNames.get(i), colValues.get(i)));
            }
            rowCounter++;

            //insert rows of block size 100
            if (rowCounter % 100==0) { 

                mutator.execute();
                //clear data
                colNames = new ArrayList<String>();
                colValues = new ArrayList<String>();
                mutator = HFactory.createMutator(keyspace, stringSerializer);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Multithreading will help a lot, yes.  At the moment, you are using one connection in Cassandra which means you are only using a single thread inside Cassandra.  You need to use multiple connections, which requires multiple threads in your client.

One way would be to use a Java ThreadPoolExecutor and wrap your mutator.execute() in a runnable and execute it on the thread pool.  Take care to handle exceptions.  You should also use a BlockingQueue to limit the number of queued mutations in case you read off your source faster than Cassandra can insert.

With this, set your connection pool size in Hector to something like 10 and your inserts should be significantly faster.

On a side note in case you weren't aware, Cassandra isn't designed for single node operation.  I assume you are intending to scale and add replication.  If not then you will probably find an alternative solution more performant and simpler for your needs.  The multiple connections and threads become especially important when using multiple nodes so your insert rate can scale.

Comment: thanks for your answer! So I will need multiple nodes if I want to make my client multi-threaded? I have no knowledge of multi-threading, I wonder if you are aware of any good multi-thread cassandra examples online?

Yes, I am currently in test now and will expand to more nodes later on.  @Richard

Comment: No, you can have many connections per node, which is all you need to make your client multi-threaded.  I don't know about Cassandra examples, but the javadoc for ThreadPoolExecutor is good http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html and there is a tutorial on Java threading here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: Thanks again @Richard. Sorry for another newbie question - Looks like I will wrap my code above inside Runnable and create many threads and send in different "Table" objects. My question is, should I use create a new Cluster/Mutator/Keyspace object for each of the threads or the same one?

Comment: Use the came Cluster and Keyspace object, but you will need new Mutator objects for each runnable you create.